# how to save clusterer model into arff or csv file (WEKA JAVA)

Tags: java, weka

Is there any way to do so?  I know how to save the cluster model , but not sure how to save arff file.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Instances dataSet = getInstancesSomePlace();
 ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
 saver.setInstances(dataSet);
 saver.setFile(new File("./data/test.arff"));
 saver.setDestination(new File("./data/test.arff"));   
 saver.writeBatch();
```

I used this form to save the clustering result in an data.arrf
https://weka.wikispaces.com/Save+Instances+to+an+ARFF+File